# How does Tooley's "simple world" refute the counterfactual account of causality?

Tags: metaphysics, causation

In [Causation: Reductionism Versus Realism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2108040), Michael Tooley proposes a thought experiment where we imagine a simple world with only two "causal laws":

> For any object x, x's having property P for a temporal interval of
> length  At either causes x to acquire property Q, or else causes x to
> acquire  property R, but does not do both;
>
> For any object x, x's having property S for a temporal interval of
> length  At either causes x to acquire property Q, or else causes x to
> acquire  property R, but does not do both.

He then asks us to imagine a case where an object a acquires both properties P and S, and go on to acquire property Q and R. The quotation goes on,

> Here, a has acquired both property Q and property R, and, as a
> result,  there are two possibilities concerning the relevant causal
> relations:
>
> Possibility 1
> Pa causes Qa, and Sa causes Ra
>
> Possibility 2
> Pa causes Ra, and Sa causes Qa
>
> One is therefore confronted with the question of what the relevant causal
> relations are. Was it the possession of property P, for the appropriate
> interval, that caused the acquisition of property Q, and the possession of S
> that caused the acquisition of R? Or was it, instead, the other way
> around? **Given a reductionist view, however, no answer is possible.**
> *(Emphasis mine)*

But it seems to me that the counterfactual account of causation has no problem with this. In the counterfactual world where object a never had P, for instance, the object would fail to acquire one of either Q or R. Whichever one that would have been, that's the property which would have been caused by P.

Why does Tooley believe that this analysis is impossible or inadequate?